# Not able to insert data to a table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I am not able to insert data to table. Please find the below error which I get.

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]An explicit value for
>   the identity column in table 'CREDP_EMP_ACCESSORIES_PROCESSED' can
>   only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is
>   ON.

I even tried to set IDENTITY_INSERT to ON. 
Please find the code I used.

[image]

Comment: Image won't help, paste your code to the question.

Comment: sqllist = "delete  CREDP_EMP_ACCESSORIES_PROCESSED  where ACC_SYS = " & accsys 
response.Write sqllist & "delete query" & "<br>"
set rso = con.execute(sqllist)

sqllist = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT CREDP_EMP_ACCESSORIES_PROCESSED ON"
response.Write sqllist & "<br>"
set rso = con.execute(sqllist)
sqllist = "INSERT into CREDP_EMP_ACCESSORIES_PROCESSED SELECT ACC_SYS, ACC_CODE, ACC_DESC, ACC_CRDT,  ACC_CRID, ACC_CRNAME, ACC_GROUP, ACC_TYPE ,ACC_YEAR, ACC_QTR, ACC_MTH FROM CREDP_EMP_ACCESSORIES_UPLOAD_HEAD where ACC_SYS = " & accsys 

set rso = con.execute(sqllist)

Answer (score 0):

When you set sqlserver Identity Insert ON, you have to provide identity column value.

so, as per your image, found that you did not provide identity value.

if you insert identity value from another table, set identity insert on otherwise set 
identity insert off.

Maksud

Comment: An explicit value for the identity column in table 'CREDP_EMP_ACCESSORIES_PROCESSED' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON. This is what I get when I try to insert

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved after making the identity column in CREDP_EMP_ACCESSORIES_PROCESSED a regular (non-identity) int column since it's an archive table